# On duality gap in general non-convex problems

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to solve a non-convex constrained minimization problem. From my understanding, the dual function is always concave and provides a lower-bound to the primal problem for any dual variable(s). Since it is concave, (if it is nice enough) I should be able to solve it using an interior-point algorithm and numerically obtain a lower bound to the primal.

Now, imagine I have found a feasible solution to the primal problem that gives a primal objective value very close to the optimal dual objective value. My questions are:

1. Does that mean my feasible solution is near optimal? Is this a good way to check if the duality gap is large Or small? or are there more efficient ways to do that?
2. Why do people try to reformulate or approximate a primal problem with a convex problem even when the duality gap is small enough?

Comment: Define "near optimal"  Is a solution to a badly conditioned problem near optimal only if the solution is close to the optimal solution or is having a solution with a nearly optimal objective value good enough?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just changed my question a bit to make my point clearer. As long as the objective values are close, to me, it is near optimal.

Comment: 1. Yes, as you state, if you find $x$ that satisfies the constraints and $f(x)\leq d(\mu)+\epsilon$ for some $\mu$ and some $\epsilon>0$ it means the duality gap is at most $\epsilon$ and $x$ is near optimal since $f(x)\leq f^*+\epsilon$. But, it is not clear how to find such an $x$, even if one exists. 2. We don’t always know if the duality gap is small or large, and even if we know it is small it may not be easy to find a primal solution that satisfies the constraints and that has small $f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll vote it as an answer if you post your comment below.